# Retrieving double value from Android Room cause NullPointerExcpetion

Tags: java, android, database, nullpointerexception, android-room

I have an android room DB with the next POJO

```
  Entity(tableName = "transactions")
    public class BoardItem {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        int itemID;
        String account;
        String date;
        String category;
        double value:
//getters and setters
    }
```

For the load sum of all value for a specified category, I try to use the next DAO

```
@Query ("SELECT category, SUM (value) as total FROM transactions WHERE category =:transactionCategory GROUP BY category ")
double getAllTransactionInCategory(String transactionCategory);
```

And next code in repository android room :

```
public class RoomTransactionsRepository {
    private final RoomTransactionsDAO mTransactionsDao;
    private final LiveData<List<TransactionBoardItem>> mAllTransactions;

    RoomTransactionsRepository(Application application){
            RoomTransactionsDatabase db = RoomTransactionsDatabase.getDatabase(application);
            mTransactionsDao = db.transactions_dao();
            mAllTransactions = mTransactionsDao.getAllTransactions();
    }

    LiveData<List<TransactionBoardItem>> getAllTransactions(){
        return mAllTransactions;
    }

    double getAllTransactionInCategory (String category){
        return mTransactionsDao.getAllTransactionInCategory (category);
    }

    //Livedata code...
```

But after attempts to display data in text view on every other way it throws next NullPointerException despite there is such data in db (checked in Android Studio db inspector):

```
2021-05-20 21:38:06.800 6673-6673/com.example.dbexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dbexample, PID: 6673
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dbexample/com.example.dbexample.transactions.TransactionStatisticActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.example.dbexample.transactions.RoomTransactionsRepository.getAllTransactionInCategory(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.example.dbexample.transactions.RoomTransactionsRepository.getAllTransactionInCategory(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dbexample.transactions.TransactionStatisticActivity.onCreate(TransactionStatisticActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
```

To display I use the next code:

```
public class StatisticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RoomTransactionsRepository repository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // init code 

         binding.totalValue.setText (String.valueOf (repository.getAllTransactionInCategory ("Food")));
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong in DAO or Repository code that causes NullPointerException when I try to display double value that I want to extract from db?
Thanks in advance!

Update: VievModel class. It in use in separate activity to insert data from DB into RecyclerView dynamically.

```
public class RoomTransactionsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final RoomTransactionsRepository mRepo;
    private final LiveData<List<TransactionItem>> mAllTransactions;

    public RoomTransactionsViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        mRepo = new RoomTransactionsRepository(application);
        mAllTransactions  = mRepo.getAllTransactions();
    }

    LiveData<List<TransactionBoardItem>> getAllTransactions(){
        return mAllTransactions;
    }

    public void insert(TransactionItem item){mRepo.insertTransaction(item);}
    public void deleteAll(){mRepo.deleteAllTransactions();}
    
}
```

UPDATE 2: I modified answer, but used slightly different approach to solve my question.
STEP 1: i create POJO for rows that I want to extract:

```
public class TransactionStatisticItem {
    //`@ColumnInfo(name = "")` should equal to name of row in your DB
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    double  transactionValue;//+

   //getters

    public TransactionStatisticItem(double transactionValue, String transactionCategory) {
        this.transactionValue = transactionValue;
        this.transactionCategory = transactionCategory;
    }
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category")
    String transactionCategory;//+
}
```

STEP 2: I created interface   as it was in answer but replaced double with POJO class `void onReturned(TransactionStatisticItem item);`
STEP 3: Uptaded Repository code based on answer but with changes :

```
//To retrieve data asynchronous from DB you can use : ExecutorService (java) / Coroutines (kotlin) or AsyncTask (deprecated in API level 30)
 public static final ExecutorService singleThreadExecutor =
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    void getAllTransactionInCategory (String category, TransactionStatisticListener listener){
            singleThreadExecutor.execute(() -> listener.onReturned(mTransactionsDao.getAllTransactionInCategory (category)));
        }
```

STEP 4: and to the ViewModel, i add the next lines

```
 void getAllTransactionInCategory (String category, TransactionStatisticListener listener){
        mRepo.getAllTransactionInCategory (category, listener);
    }
```

STEP 5: and finally in Activity i add next code:

```
RoomTransactionsViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider (this).get(RoomTransactionsViewModel.class);

        model.getAllTransactionInCategory("Food", item -> {
            binding.totalValue.setText (String.valueOf (item.getTransactionValue ()));
            binding.category.setText (String.valueOf (item.getTransactionCategory ()));
        });
```

In the end, I was able to retrieve next example data: sum for all transactions in the "Food" category.

Comment: Can you show where do you initialize `RoomTransactionsRepository` & the ViewModel instances

Comment: @Zain updated, this is it? ViewModel involved in the separate activity to give the possibility to insert POJO items in RecyclerView dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> binding.totalValue.setText (String.valueOf (repository.getAllTransactionInCategory ("Food")));
> ```

For pursuing Google MVVM guidelines, you shouldn't access Repository from the activity, as it's considered a layer to the database that should not handled by the View, but by the `ViewModel`

The other issue that you return a double value from database without using a listener; as taking values from database takes some time, so `getAllTransactionInCategory()` won't return the expected value. This can be solved by using a listener interface, or returning a `LiveData<Double>` and observing it in the activity.

**Applying that:**

So, instead it's recommended to access this through the `ViewModel`:

Dao: return a `LiveData<Double>`

```
@Query ("SELECT category, SUM (value) as total FROM transactions WHERE category =:transactionCategory GROUP BY category ")
LiveData<Double> getAllTransactionInCategory(String transactionCategory);
```

ViewModel:

```
public class RoomTransactionsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   
   // ...
    
    
    LiveData<Double> getAllTransactionInCategory (String category){
        return mRepo.getAllTransactionInCategory (category);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class RoomTransactionsRepository {

    //.....
    
    LiveData<Double> getAllTransactionInCategory (String category){
        return mTransactionsDao.getAllTransactionInCategory (category);
    }
```

And observe the `LiveData` in activity:

```
public class StatisticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RoomTransactionsRepository repository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // init code 
        
        
        RoomTransactionsViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RoomTransactionsViewModel.class);
        
        
        model.getAllTransactionInCategory("Food").observe(this, new Observer<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Double value) {
                binding.totalValue.setText (value);
            }
        });
        
      //  binding.totalValue.setText (String.valueOf (model.getAllTransactionInCategory ("Food")));
        
        
        
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

> "This can be solved by using a listener interface" can you elaborate, please

To use a listener, you need an interface that has a callback method that accepts the type you want to return from Room, in this case it's a `double`

```
public interface TransactionListener {
     void onReturned(double count);
}
```

Then use an implementation of this interface when Room returns the value as follows:

Dao:

```
@Query ("SELECT category, SUM (value) as total FROM transactions WHERE category =:transactionCategory GROUP BY category ")
double getAllTransactionInCategory(String transactionCategory);
```

ViewModel:

```
public class RoomTransactionsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   
   // ...
    
    
    void getAllTransactionInCategory (String category, TransactionListener listener){
        mRepo.getAllTransactionInCategory (category, listener);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class RoomTransactionsRepository {

    //.....
    
    void getAllTransactionInCategory (String category, TransactionListener listener){
 
        listener.onReturned(mTransactionsDao.getAllTransactionInCategory (category));
    }
```

Activity:

```
public class StatisticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RoomTransactionsRepository repository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // init code 
        
        
        RoomTransactionsViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RoomTransactionsViewModel.class);
        
            
        model.getAllTransactionInCategory("Food", new TransactionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReturned(double count) {
                binding.totalValue.setText (String.valueOf (count));
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! "This can be solved by using a listener interface" can you elaborate, please ? I also updated post, with additional info about what I want.

Comment: @GremlinShX Please check UPDATE section in answer.

Comment: Thanks you, I used your answer as the basis for answering my own question, but with changes, you can check update3 in the question. And one more thing, you have a mistake: void getAllTransactionInCategory in ViewModel class shouldn't use the "return" keyword.